# how to send gmail using nodemailer (solution of less secure app deprecated)

Tags: node.js, express, smtp, gmail, nodemailer

I am trying to send mail using `nodemailer` node module and configured like this.

```
  ... config.js ...
  smtp: {
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "***@gmail.com",
      pass: "****"
    }
  }
  ... mail.js ...
  const config = require("../config");
  const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(config.smtp);

  const sendEmail = async (data, res) => {
    // if(!data.to || !data.subject)
    //     return false;
    
    data = { ...data, from: config.smtp.auth.user };
    console.log(data)
    transporter.sendMail(data, (error, info) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.send(error);
    });
    res.send(true)
  }

  module.exports = sendEmail;

  ... controller ...
  router.get('/testEmail', async (req, res) => {
    let emailData = {
      to: "***@gmail.com",
      subject: "Welcome to Musical World",
      text: "test test"
    };
    let result = sendEmail(emailData, res);
    console.log(result)
    // res.send(result);
  })
```

When I try to send email, it returns

```
{"code":"EAUTH","response":"535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials p25-20020a056638217900b0033c14d2386bsm898629jak.75 - gsmtp","responseCode":535,"command":"AUTH PLAIN"}
```

So I did googling and found that's why I didn't turn on less secure app in my google account.
But when I went there, google said

[image]

I tried to turn on `less secure apps` , but G`less secure apps` feature isn't available.

[image]

What do I have to do , then?

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved by myself!.

Google no longer supports `less secure app` feature from 05/20/2022.
It will help other developers who get stuck with this issue.

So we can't access to gmail using only `emal and password`.
Instead we have to use `OAuth2` to get access to gmail.

```
... config.js ...
  smtp: {
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      type: "OAuth2",
      user: "*****@gmail.com",
      pass: "******",
      clientId: "********",
      clientSecret: "***********",
      refreshToken: "************"
    }
  }
```

You have to have OAuth2 client in your google cloud console for this.
Here's full details you can refer to.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/use-nodemailer-to-send-emails-from-your-node-js-server/